# multiple scripts in CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA fail

Tags: cmake, c++14

```
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA "./postinst; ./prerm ")
```

I have a postinst and a prerm script in CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA in the same order as mentioned. When I install my application, postinst script executes as it is the first one. But when I uninstall my application prerm does not execute. If I change the order in which scripts are defined in `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA`, prerm executes before uninstallation, but postinst does not execute.

How can I make sure both of them execute when they are supposed to?
Will this work with conffiles and postrm in the mix as well?

Answer (score -1):

You are close to having it correct, you will need to switch your ./ to ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}

like so:

```
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/postinst" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/postrm")
```

as an extra note ensure that all the permissions are set correctly (i.e. executable)
hope this helps

ps
you can check the files have been inserted to the deb package by using the command

```
sudo dpkg -e DebPackage.deb /some/location/
```

Comment: In my experience, you almost certainly will want to use `set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_STRICT_PERMISSION TRUE)` - or else the permissions on the `postinst` scripts will be `0777`, regardless of the permissions in your code repository. You can check by looking at the files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/<package_name>.*` once the package is installed (or use `lintian` to tell you without installing the package).